# boost::asio::async_read loops infinite with zero byte of received data

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio

I am trying to write IO_Service based async TCP client where Async_write works fine but async_read runs in infinite loop . During my trial to rectify the issue i found that in all the other cases async_read just stops receiving data , it receives nothing until i stop the server. Below is the code and the links which i tried before posting my query.

The suggestions i tried are [exactly as mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639286/boost-asio-async-read-doesnt-stop-reading) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527443/problems-using-boostasioasync-read) , [3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060671/boostasiobuffer-getting-the-buffer-size-and-preventing-buffer-overflow) but in all the cases my async_read handler does not read anything . In one and only one case it start infinite loop when i set buffer as  `boost::asio::mutable_buffer bytes;` in rest cases i have tried `boost::array<char, 512> bytes;` , `boost::asio::streambuf bytes;` and `char bytes[512];` where the async_read handler is not raised.

After going through all of these solution I am now confused : can it be the problem of buffer ? Do I need to initialize it before passing to read
?

Please guide.

```
ScalableSocket::ScalableSocket()
{
    //ctor

    using namespace boost::asio;
    service = boost::make_shared<io_service>();
    work =    boost::make_shared<io_service::work>(*service );
    strand  = boost::make_shared<io_service::strand>( *service );
    worker_threads = boost::make_shared<boost::thread_group>();



        worker_threads->create_thread(boost::bind(&ScalableSocket::WorkerThread,this));


    resolver = boost::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver> (*service);

    tcp_socket= boost::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> (*service);

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query q(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(),"192.168.100.96","9602");

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it = resolver->resolve(q);

    boost::asio::async_connect(*tcp_socket,it,boost::bind(&ScalableSocket::connect_handler,this,boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    tcp_socket->set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true) );

}

ScalableSocket::~ScalableSocket()
{
    //dtor

}

void ScalableSocket::PublishPost()
{
    strand->post(boost::bind(&ScalableSocket::OnSend,this));
}


void ScalableSocket::OnSend()
{


    boost::array<char, 6> a = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };

    boost::asio::async_write(*tcp_socket,boost::asio::buffer(a),
                                    boost::bind(&ScalableSocket::write_handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));



}

void ScalableSocket::WorkerThread()
{
    while( true )
    {
        try
        {
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            service->run( ec );
            if( ec )
            {
                ///LOGE(ec);
            }
            break;
        }
        catch( std::exception & ex )
        {
            ///LOGE(ex.what());
        }
    }
}

void ScalableSocket::connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec)
{
    if (!ec)
    {

    PublishPost();




/* boost::asio::async_read(*tcp_socket,
                                boost::asio::buffer(bytes),
                                boost::bind(&ScalableSocket::read_handler, this,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
*/

        ///https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527443/problems-using-boostasioasync-read

        boost::shared_ptr<boost::array<char, 512>> buf(new boost::array<char, 512>);


        boost::asio::async_read(*tcp_socket,boost::asio::buffer(*buf),
                                boost::bind(&ScalableSocket::read_handler, this,buf,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    }
    else
    {
        cout<<" Some error connecting to Exchange  "<< ec.message()<<endl;

    }

}


void ScalableSocket::OnTimer(const boost::system::error_code &ec)
{
    if(!ec)
    {
        printf("\n\n Heartbeat event raised sending KeepAlive to exchange \n\n");
        PublishPost();
        HeartBeatTimer->async_wait(boost::bind(&ScalableSocket::OnTimer,this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
}

void ScalableSocket::recvData()
{
    boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::array<char, 1024> buf;

    //for(;;)
    {
        size_t len = tcp_socket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

        cout<<"\n Recv data size is "<<len;

    }
}

void ScalableSocket::read_handler(boost::shared_ptr<boost::array<char, 512>> buf,const boost::system::error_code &ec,std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{


    if (!ec )//&& bytes_transferred > 0)
    {

        ///recvData(); /// If i enable this code during infinite loop it start getting data that means socket has no issue

        cout << " Data size recieved "<< bytes_transferred<<endl;




            boost::asio::async_read(*tcp_socket,boost::asio::buffer(*buf),
                                boost::bind(&ScalableSocket::read_handler, this,buf,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    else
    {
        /// Some issue with socket publish error , inform user and reconnect
        cout<<" Some error reading data from Exchange  "<< ec.message()<<endl;

    }
}

void ScalableSocket::write_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error,std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        /// data Sent successfully
        cout<< " Data sent size "<< bytes_transferred<<endl;

    }
    else
    {
        cout<<" Some error sending data to Exchange  "<< error.message()<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: But you know that `asnyc_read` will NOT "return" / call the handler until the given buffer is completely full, right ?

Comment: I used this 512 kind of buffer once I failed to receive anything using boost streambuffer or mutable buffer then I tried using that 512 thing following some solution on stack itself

Comment: Some punctuation marks would help to identify your comment. Try sending data with 512 byte & more and see if you receive it correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Blacktempel for saving me . You were 100% right . It was all my fault. Replaced asio::async_read to socket.async_read_some and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asnyc_read`will NOT "return" / call the handler until the given buffer is completely full.

`asnyc_read_some` will return after some bytes have been read. This might be the function you're looking for.

Remember to handle received data correctly with `asnyc_read_some`. If you send 512 bytes, it may arrive in a couple of reads, depending on the machine.